# Identify UIAlertViews by their titles without the title being displayed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, delegates, uialertview

I wonder if it is possible to show a `UIAlertView` without displaying its non-`nil` title. If the title is `nil` or `@""`, it will be not displayed. But here I want to use the title to dispatch inside my delegate that handles all the different `UIAlertView` button clicks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your delegate doesn't have pointers to the `UIAlertView`s it's responsible for, you can use each alert view's [`tag`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW25) property, which it inherits from `UIView`, to distinguish them.

Answer (score 1):

You could also associate an object with your UIAlertView using `objc_[set|get]AssociatedObject()`. Check `<objc/runtime.h>`. Or use Josh's answer.